# Create ParametricFunction object without ParametricNDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, interpolation

Documentation of v9 states that `ParametricFunction` is generated by `ParametricNDSolve` and `ParametricNDSolveValue`.

Is there any way of creating `ParametricFunction` by definition, similar to creating an `InterpolatingFunction` by `Interpolation`?

My motivation behind is that for certain parameters, I need solution of `ParametricNDSolveValue` to be returned and for other parameters I want to use analytical solution to be returner in the same format -`ParametricFunction`.

Comment: why don't you just return the analytical solution as a `Function[args, Evaluate[analyticalSolution]]`?

Comment: thanks for idea! I'm going to put example and my answer to it for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Assume an example function which will switch behaviour depending on `c` being `True` or `False`. This solution is based on comment of @ruebenko.

```
fun[c_] := Module[{x, a, b, t},
            If[c,
               ParametricNDSolveValue[{
               x''[t] + a x'[t] + b^2 x[t] == 0, 
               x[0] == 1, 
               x'[0] == 0},
               x, {t, 0, 10}, {a, b}],
               (*else*)
               Function[{a, b}, 
                Interpolation[{#, #^2} & /@Range[0, 10, 1]
                (*same range of t in InterpolatingFunction as from ParametricNDSolveValue*)]]
            ]
          ]
```

Now we call `fun` with :

```
fTrue = fun[True]
fFalse = fun[False]
(*ParametricFunction[<>]*)
(*Function[{a, b}, Interpolation[({#1, #1^2} &) /@ Range[0, 10, 1]]]*)
```

We can address both resulting functions like a `ParametricFunction` and get an `InterpolatingFunction`:

```
fTrue[1, 1]
fFalse[1, 1]
(* InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,10.}},<>] *)
(* InterpolatingFunction[{{0,10}},<>] *)
```